# Safari 16.1 add weird shadow to images

Tags: html, css, safari, mobile-safari

After updating safari to **version 16.1**, I noticed that images on my website have a weird shadow as shown below in the screenshot.

The HTML code :

```
<img src="gitHub.png" alt="github" class="max-w-[130px]">
```

and I use Tailwind CSS.[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. Please could you put just enough code into your question which we can run and which definitely shows the problem on Safari. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There is no other code I can put, It's simple, Adding an image in HTML using img Tag. In Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Edge the image is displayed normally, but Safari version 16.1 displays the image with a weird shadow.

Comment: Please put it as a runnable snippet and check that it does actually show the problem. Just copying the code you have given and running it with an img I have sourced does not produce that shadow,